# Access permission for multiple facebook apps at a time

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a single website that is going to be hosting multiple Facebook applications (both in Facebook as apps and on the web through Facebook connect).

The issue I am running into is when I perform a Facebook connect I pass a single application with that applications parameters. This causes issues if the user then tries to use another application since they have not "logged in/granted permission" in that other application.

Is anyone aware of a solution to connect to multiple facebook applications at once?

Answer (score 2):

You must connect to each Facebook application one at a time.

You can't expect a user to grant permissions to 1 app then automatically give permissions to other apps as well.

Once they have granted each application though, you can automatically log them in to them all without going through each one. But the initial granting of permissions must be there for each app.